# Unable to load Maven meta-data from android-sdk.payfort.com maven-metadata.xml

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, payfort

I'm trying to integrate Amazon Payment Services Android SDK. I have a below issue acquired. I'm try to resolve the issue to upgrade the `Gradle build version` and wrapper `distributionUrl` on following this [Link](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Flutter-SDK/issues/428) but it's not working.

> Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://android-sdk.payfort.com/androidx/core/core-ktx/maven-metadata.xml.

> Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not GET 'https://android-sdk.payfort.com/androidx/core/core-ktx/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

This is my App Gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven{ url "https://jitpack.io"}
        maven { url "https://android-sdk.payfort.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In My gradle-wrapper.properties also change the version `gradle-6.7.1-all.zip`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```